# save user specific data

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, web

I'm building a html app which will be loaded in a web view in an iphone app. How can I save user specific data without user accounts stored in a database?

I can't access the iphone's UDID inside the html app, I don't think it's possible to send it from the iphone app to html app. I have the PHP session ID which is unique for current users but won't work for returning ones.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Safari on iOS offers, I believe, a number of ways to store data on the client-side using HTML5. Apple's own [Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) explains the possibilities, including simple Key-Value parings, if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do that is to use cookies.

Another modern way to do it would be to do offline storage, but I don't know if iOS Safari supports it.

But specifically about your case, I'd make the web app generate a number or identifier for every person. That number would be saved once in the native app, and then be passed to the web app.

Comment: any idea what is the maximum storage space for cookies? I would need to store a really large array (serialised).

Comment: I thought you would do the storage on the server and only store the user ID in the cookie, as it's done with a session ID for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a little early, but we're starting to see some adoption of a client side databases in browsers, but once again, still not standardized.

http://www.webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/